# Sort with multiple columns

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am using SSAS Tabular model and I want to sort my table using two columns, how can I do that? I can sort it using one column, but I couldn't find a way to sort the table with multiple columns.

Comment: You can use direct query and sort your columns in SQL using Order By clause.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you want to apply a general sort order to the entire table? This is not possible in SSAS Tabular. When you sort a column within SSDT, this is only for preview purposes, as the order of rows in the table does not matter when you execute a DAX query against the model. You can, however, specify a sort order for individual columns, based on another column. If you intend to sort a column on two or more columns, read on. If your intention was to have the result of a DAX query be sorted in a specific ways, simply use the [`ORDER BY` clause](https://dax.guide/st/order-by/).

**Sorting a column based on two or more columns**

A column in a table can be sorted by any one other column. If you need to sort a column by two or more columns, create a composite column and then use that for sorting.

For example, say your table contains columns named [SortPrimary] and [SortSecondary]. Create a new (calculated) column with the expression: `MyTable[SortPrimary] & "|" & MyTable[SortSecondary]`. Make sure to concatenate the columns using a character that doesn't appear in either column.